# T-SQL Grouping With Splits

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to group on consecutive like values. I want to group the first 3 Reg Unit, the one ICU and the last 3 Reg Unit. The problem is the 3rd group is the same as the first group and I'm unable to group them separately. I've tried window functions and other things to no avail. Would appreciate any ideas. Thanks.

Dataset

```
ID  OccpdID   Unit
1     1       Reg
1     2       Reg
1     3       Reg
1     4       ICU
1     5       Reg
1     6       Reg
1     7       Reg
```

Result to be:

```
ID  OccpdID Unit    Group
1     1     Reg      1
1     2     Reg      1
1     3     Reg      1
1     4     ICU      2
1     5     Reg      3
1     6     Reg      3
1     7     Reg      3
```

Comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `LAG` in a subquery with `SUM`and `CASE WHEN` window function.

```
SELECT ID,OccpdID,Unit,SUM(CASE WHEN Unit <> prevVal THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(ORDER BY OccpdID) +1 as 'Group'
FROM (
    SELECT *, LAG(Unit) OVER(ORDER BY OccpdID) prevVal
    FROM Dataset
) t1
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=670da6eb7cfa859e2ec02223eb98d25d)

Comment: Thank you, This one worked for me. The other submissions were good too. I will take each of these and learn from them. Thank you for your quick responses and time...........

Comment: @DonaldB No problem glad to help you can upvote other answer if them help you

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how/if you want the ID to factor into it, but something like this will provide the desired results:

```
SELECT
    ID
    , OccpdID
    , Unit
    , SUM(CASE WHEN Unit <> L OR L IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (ORDER BY OccpdID) [Group]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ID
            , OccpdID
            , Unit
            , LAG(Unit, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY OccpdID) L
        FROM YourTable
    ) Q
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `lag()` and a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when prev_unit = unit then 0 else 1 end) over (order by occpdid) as grp
from (select t.*, lag(t.unit) over (order by t.occpdid) as prev_unit
      from t
     ) t;
```